# Tableau: Using the "Include Only" and "Exclude" User Filters

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I'm using tableau to make a dashboard, and I have run into an issue with the "Include All" and 'Exclude" selections you can make in the mouse-over tooltips. When you mouse over a data point, or select several at once, you can choose either of these options to filter your data down (either by limiting it to those you have selected, or by excluding those you have selected).

I feel like an idiot for not figuring this out (or finding an answer on google), but

1. How does one turn off the filter after it's been set? 
   I know it shows up in the filters box, but I am referring specifically to when you have the visualisation opened as either a dashboard or using Tableau Reader. It seems to me that there is no way to actually turn off these filters once you've applied them, except through use of the "undo" button.
2. Additionally, I would like to be able to apply these filters to more than one sheet; for example, say I have two visualisations on one dashboard - one is a geo-spatial map, and the other is a chart of some kind. If the user selects a few points on the map and clicks "Include Only", it would be very neat if I could get that filter to also apply to the chart on the same screen.

My sincerest apologies if there's a fairly straightforward answer to these questions, but I really couldn't find any info on google and I couldn't figure it out through playing with the software itself.

Cheers,

Ollie

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want your users to change the filter settings then you need make the filter visible (click on `Show filter` in the filter section). 
   If you want to make this change as an admin then you need to go to a worksheet in question and change the filter settings.
2. Go to `Filter` and click on `Apply to worksheets` and choose the worksheets you need. 
   Or click on a map (worksheet) and choose `Use as filter` from the dropdown in the top right corner of a worksheet.

I hope this helps.